# Quickest way to update headers of millions of images on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I have couple of millions folder that contains images inside like this

```
s3://test/1000/
s3://test/1001/
...
```

Each folder contains 5-10 images like `s3://test/1000/1000-small.jpg`. I am trying to set `Cache-Control` header for all of the images here using `s3cmd`

```
s3cmd --recursive modify --remove-header=Expires --add-header='Cache-Control:max-age=31536000, public' s3://test/1000/
```

It takes too long to update the images. Like **15k** folders/day. So I have to wait for a long long time, unless I cut the file that contains list of all folders and run the command on different machine.

Just want to ask is there any possible way to run the same task faster?

Thank you!

### UPDATE!

As I remember, at the end I just get the list of folders, then I split that into multiple files, then run multiple s3cmd commands for each file. At the end it take a couple of hours to finish.

Comment: Have you tried running this command on a EC2 instance in the same region as the S3 bucket to reduce latency?

Comment: Did you ever find a fast way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the official aws cli tool ?

```
aws s3 sync /path s3://yourbucket/ --recursive --cache-control max-age=604800
```

Comment: This method is very slow, looking for a better way